# JSON multiple queries at once

Tags: json, python-3.x, error-handling

I have a python method that captures the folloing JSON info :

```
{'info': {'orderId': 5913316, 'clientOrderId': 'ME_dot', 'origQty': '0.02000000', 'trade': 'xxx', 'updateTime': xxx, 'side': 'BUY', 'timeInForce': 'GTC', 'status': 'FILLED', 'stopPrice': '0.0', 'time': xxx, 'isWorking': True, 'type': 'LIMIT', 'price': '506.10887700', 'executedQty': '0.02000000'}, 'lastTradeTimestamp': None, 'remaining': 0.0, 'fee': None, 'timestamp': x, 'symbol': 'xxx', 'trades': None, 'datetime': 'xxx, 'price': 0.108877, 'amount': 0.02, 'cost': 0.00217754, 'status': 'closed', 'type': 'limit', 'id': '59139516', 'filled': 0.02, 'side': 'buy'}
```

from it, I just need to capture `clientOrderId` and `executedQty` so i am trying the following:

```
id, q  =  (exchange.order_status(trading )['info']['clientOrderId'], ['info']['executedQty'])
```

that brings this problem: `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str`

so How could I capture the values in the same line code?

Answer (score 2):

First you need to convert your JSON string into a JSON object. But your `json` in the question is improperly formatted for directly converting it. So,

Properly enclose your JSON in `""`. Here's a properly formatted one.

```
order_status = '{"info": {"orderId": 5913316, "clientOrderId": "ME_dot", "origQty": "0.02000000", "trade": "xxx", "updateTime": "xxx", "side": "BUY", "timeInForce": "GTC", "status": "FILLED", "stopPrice": "0.0", "time": "xxx", "isWorking": "True", "type": "LIMIT", "price": "506.10887700", "executedQty": "0.02000000"}, "lastTradeTimestamp": "None", "remaining": 0.0, "fee": "None", "timestamp": "x", "symbol": "xxx", "trades": "None", "datetime": "xxx", "price": 0.108877, "amount": 0.02, "cost": 0.00217754, "status": "closed", "type": "limit", "id": "59139516", "filled": 0.02, "side": "buy"}'
```

Once that's done you can,

```
import json
order_status_json = json.loads(order_status)
```

This will convert the string into `JSON` object, Now you can query values easily.

Like this,

```
p, q  =  (order_status_json['info']['clientOrderId'],order_status_json['info']['executedQty'])
```

Returns,

```
>>> p

'ME_dot'
>>> q

'0.02000000'
```

Comment: @Esteban G. Gutierrez Accept the answer if it helped you to mark it as solved.